# Align Button To The center Of the window using pysimplegui

Tags: python, user-interface, pysimplegui

In my application am trying to place my button,text and input at the center of the window.I am using **PySimpleGUI** for designing buttons.For aligning to the center i used `justification='center'` attribute on my code.But still it is not fitting to the center of the window.

The code am working with is

```
import PySimpleGUI as sg
from tkinter import * 
sg.theme('DarkAmber')  
layout = [ 
        [sg.Text('Enter the value',justification='center')],
        [sg.Input(justification='center')],
        [sg.Button('Enter','center')]
     ]


  window = sg.Window('My new window', layout, size=(500,300), grab_anywhere=True)

 while True:
event, values = window.read()   # Read the event that happened and the values dictionary
print(event, values)
if event == sg.WIN_CLOSED or event == 'Exit':     # If user closed window with X or if user clicked "Exit" button then exit
    break
if event == 'Button':
  print('You pressed the button')
window.close()
```

The above code outputs 
[image] 
How can i make the text,button and input to the center of the window?

Comment: Maybe look at the demo program "Demo_Layout_Vertical_Centered.py" on the project's GitHub.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

this code make the text, button and input to the center of the window.

```
import PySimpleGUI as sg
sg.theme('DarkAmber')  
layout = [ 
        [sg.Text('Enter the value',justification='center',size=(100,1))],
        [sg.Input(justification='center',size=(100,1))],
        [sg.Button('Enter','center',size=(100,1))]
     ]


window = sg.Window('My new window', layout, size=(500,300), grab_anywhere=True)

while True:
    event, values = window.read()   # Read the event that happened and the values dictionary
    print(event, values)
    if event == None or event == 'Exit':     # If user closed window with X or if user clicked "Exit" button then exit
        break
    if event == 'Button':
      print('You pressed the button')
    window.close()
```

Comment: @BharGav Desai - that code doesn't centre the button, it centres the text within the button that's full width. If you make the button eg size(10,1), it's still on the left of the screen. The element_justification='c' is required to centre the button on the screen - but that centres everything.
Ideally I'd like to be able to centre buttons within a frame, but have text inputs left and/or right justified in different frames within the same window.

Comment: Should be wrong code, second argument of `sg.Button` is for `button_type`. All elements not aligned center of window.

Answer (score 21):

I think this is what you're looking for

```py
window = sg.Window('My new window', layout, element_justification='c')
```

---

Edit - Centering vertically (SEE MARCH 2022 edit below for a BETTER solution)

Centering a layout vertically in a window is quite a bit bigger of a chore.  What's required are 2 elements that will expand when the window expands.  This is a demo program that is part of the Demos on the PySimpleGUI GitHub

```py
import PySimpleGUI as sg

"""
    Center a column in a window
    Solves a very specific kind of layout.
    If you want to have something centered in a Window, this is a good way to do it
    The "trick" here is:
        * the first row of the layout has a Text element that expands vertically
        * the row with the Column has a text element that expands horizontally
    
    This expanding Text element is what will cause the Column element to be centered

    Used with permission
"""

def main():
    column_to_be_centered = [  [sg.Text('My Window')],
                [sg.Input(key='-IN-')],
                [sg.Text(size=(12,1), key='-OUT-')],
                [sg.Button('Go'), sg.Button('Exit')]  ]

    layout = [[sg.Text(key='-EXPAND-', font='ANY 1', pad=(0, 0))],  # the thing that expands from top
              [sg.Text('', pad=(0,0),key='-EXPAND2-'),              # the thing that expands from left
               sg.Column(column_to_be_centered, vertical_alignment='center', justification='center',  k='-C-')]]

    window = sg.Window('Window Title', layout, resizable=True,finalize=True)
    window['-C-'].expand(True, True, True)
    window['-EXPAND-'].expand(True, True, True)
    window['-EXPAND2-'].expand(True, False, True)

    while True:             # Event Loop
        event, values = window.read()
        print(event, values)
        if event == sg.WIN_CLOSED or event == 'Exit':
            break
        if event == 'Go':
            window['-OUT-'].update(values['-IN-'])
    window.close()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

---

Edit 18-Mar-2022

Like so many things in PySimpleGUI, operations like element justification are continually evolving.  The problem, again, with StackOverflow is that these answers are not typically updated.  It's why I suggest always using the GitHub Issues to ask questions and to check the Cookbook, eCookbook and Demo Programs to get the latest techniques.

Last year two new elements were introduced that make both horizontal and vertical justification trivial.  These elements are `Push` and `VPush`.  You'll find a [recipe in the eCookbook](https://pysimplegui.trinket.io/demo-programs#/layouts/push-and-vpush-elements).

These elements "push" other elements around.  `Push` moves them horizontally and `VPush` moves them vertically.

If you put a push on both sides of elements/rows, then those elements/rows will be centered.

Here's the same layout in the above example except using these `Push` and `VPush` elements.  This solution is much shorter & much easier to understand.

```py
import PySimpleGUI as sg

def main():
    column_to_be_centered = [  [sg.Text('My Window')],
                [sg.Input(key='-IN-')],
                [sg.Text(size=(12,1), key='-OUT-')],
                [sg.Button('Go'), sg.Button('Exit')]]

    layout = [[sg.VPush()],
              [sg.Push(), sg.Column(column_to_be_centered,element_justification='c'), sg.Push()],
              [sg.VPush()]]

    window = sg.Window('Window Title', layout, size=(500,300))

    while True:
        event, values = window.read()
        if event == sg.WIN_CLOSED or event == 'Exit':
            break

    window.close()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Best one should be option `element_justification='center'` for Container `sg.Column`, maybe not all elements aligned center of window required.

[image]

```py
import PySimpleGUI as sg

sg.theme('DarkAmber')

layout_column = [
        [sg.Text('Enter the value',justification='center')],
        [sg.Input(justification='center', key='-INPUT-')],
        [sg.Button('Enter')]
]

layout = [[sg.Column(layout_column, element_justification='center')]]

window = sg.Window('My new window', layout, grab_anywhere=True)

while True:
    event, values = window.read()
    print(event, values)
    if event == sg.WIN_CLOSED or event == 'Exit':
        break
    if event == 'Button':
        print('You pressed the button')
window.close()
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want more direct control of where your elements appear, you can use the `pad` keyword inside nearly all of the elements (button, text, in, etc.).

There are two valid formats:

- `pad=(<int>, <int>)` where `pad[0]` is padding to the left and right
  and `pad[1]` is padding above and below the element.
- `pad=((<int>, <int>), (<int>, <int>))` where the first tuple is
  padding to the left (first element) and right (second element) and
  the second tuple is padding above (first) and below (second).

So, to center to elements in your code example using the `pad` keyword, you would do something like this:

```
import PySimpleGUI as sg
sg.theme('DarkAmber')
layout = [
        [sg.Text('Enter the value', pad=(190, 0))],
        [sg.Input(justification='center', pad=(75, 0))],
        [sg.Button('Enter', pad=(215, 0))]
     ]


window = sg.Window('My new window', layout,
                   size=(500, 300), grab_anywhere=True)

while True:
    # Read the event that happened and the values dictionary
    event, values = window.read()
    print(event, values)
    # If user closed window with X or if user clicked "Exit" button then exit
    if event == sg.WIN_CLOSED or event == 'Exit':
        break
    if event == 'Button':
        print('You pressed the button')
    window.close()
```

NOTE: The above code was altered slightly from the original to match PEP8 standards.

The result is:

[image: Image of new window]

Comment: As an aside, you can also justify individual elements by using `sg.Column(layout, justification='c')` inside your overall layout list. Not everything needs to be center justified.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the simplest solution is to insert a blank label to the left of the button or buttons.

```py
# center buttons using an empty label
bt: dict={'size':(4,1)}
[sg.Text('',size=(3,1)), sg.Button('Add',**bt), sg.Button('Clear',**bt)]]
```